# confusion about Class.isInstance

Tags: java, class

Is it possible in java to get the complete hierarchy of an object?
I have checked the javadoc for the Class class and i cant find such a method.
Also, what i find strange is the result for the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassLoader loader = ClassLoaderTest.class.getClassLoader();
    Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass("java.lang.Integer");
    System.out.println(clazz.getSuperclass()); //prints java.lang.Number
    System.out.println(clazz.isInstance(clazz.getSuperclass())); //returns false??

    Number number = new Integer(1);//no class cast exception
}
```

The doc for the isInstance() method says:

> Determines if the specified {@code Object} is assignment-compatible
>        * with the object represented by this {@code Class}.

So since we can assign Integer to Number, why does:

```
java.lang.Integer.class.isInstance(java.lang.Number.class);
```

return false?

Thx

Comment: What argument does that method take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-quote the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Determines if the specified `Object` is assignment-compatible *
>   with the object represented by this `Class`.

In the expression

```
java.lang.Integer.class.isInstance(java.lang.Number.class);
```

you are checking if the object returned by the expression `java.lang.Number.class` is an instance of `Integer`. **It is not, it is an instance of `java.lang.Class`.**

It should be used like

```
java.lang.Integer.class.isInstance(new Integer(1)); // if you want it to return true
```

You can pass it anything you want, but it will only return `true` if the argument used is an `Integer` or one of its sub types (but it is `final` so there aren't any).

`Integer` is a sub type of `Number`.

Any `Integer` instance can be used where a `Number` object is required.

Comment: Thx man, but what if i have an abstract class? my real life example, is, i have to check if a class extends an abstract class, so i cant instantiate it, something similar would be: Integer.class.isInstance(new Number(1)), i cant instantiate Number...

Comment: @JBoy You'll need to be more specific. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JBoy You are using the wrong method for that. You can use `Modifier.isAbstract(Number.class.getModifiers())` to check if a class is `abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the "complete hierarchy", you can recursively walk from the starting class through all its superlcasses and their implemented interfaces

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Superclasses
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Class<?> c = Integer.class;

        System.out.println("Superclasses:");
        Set<Class<?>> superclasses = superclasses(c);
        for (Class<?> s : superclasses)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static Set<Class<?>> superclasses(Class<?> c)
    {
        LinkedHashSet<Class<?>> set = new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>();
        superclasses(c, set);
        return set;
    }

    private static void superclasses(Class<?> c, Set<Class<?>> set)
    {
        if (c == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        set.add(c);
        if (c.equals(Object.class))
        {
            return;
        }
        superclasses(c.getSuperclass(), set);
        for (Class<?> i : c.getInterfaces())
        {
            superclasses(i, set);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that the situation is slightly more complicated when you als want to obtain the *generic* superclasses. For example, when you have a class like `List<Integer>` and want to obtain all superclasses including `Collection<? extends Number>` and `Iterable<? extends Serializable>`. I have implemented this, but it is a bit of a hassle, because the set of superclasses in this sense is infinite, and you have to stop somewhere...